# defで定義した自作関数の処理にnumpyを使いたい

Tags: python, numpy

ある行列の特定の要素数ごとの中央値を求め、それを入れたリストを返す関数を作ろうとしています。
現在以下のように処理を書いているのですが、これを実行すると ”NameError: name 'np' is not defined” が出てしまいます。
自作関数の処理には別のモジュールを使えないのでしょうか？
解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示願いたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
def median(array0, ran):
med = []
index = (list(range(0, ran)))

while array0.size >= len(index):
    array1 = array0[0:len(index)]
    med.append(np.median(array1))
    array0 = np.delete(array0, index)

    if array0.size < len(index):
        med.append(np.median(array0))
        break
return med
```

Comment: `import numpy as np` はされていますか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 
関数を定義しているスクリプトには記入していませんでした
"import numpy as np"を追加したところ使えるようになりました！
アドバイスありがとうございます！

Comment: 「承認」はヘルプセンター [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)に記されています, ので参考にどうぞ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npを定義した後、インデント関連で別のエラーが出ると思いましたので、アイデアを提案します。(エラーが出ないだけで質問者さんのニーズに合っているかは分かりませんが…)

改行を含めずに言うと、既存のコードの3,4,5,12行目の初めに半角スペースを入れてみました。(そうしないと、それ以降のコードが関数の定義のコードとして、認識されないと思いまして。)
1行目は質問者さんの質問に答えるためにも一応入れました。(環境次第では、不要かもです)

(jupyter notebook/Python 3で試しました)

```
import numpy as np
def median(array0, ran):
 med= []
 index = (list(range(0, ran)))

 while array0.size >= len(index):
    array1 = array0[0:len(index)]
    med.append(np.median(array1))
    array0 = np.delete(array0, index)

    if array0.size < len(index):
        med.append(np.median(array0))
        break
 return med
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、npの定義し忘れとインデントの欠如が原因でした。
丁寧な解説、とても分かりやすく勉強になりました。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 励みにもなりますので、回答に満足いただけたら、承認をお願いします。